# Polymer - Load different components dynamically

Tags: javascript, dom, dynamic, polymer, components

I'm a Polymer novice, but I guess what the answer will be...

Recently I came across with this issue: I got to loop through a collection of elements (using dom-repeat) and display its contents. But every element has a unique display and bindings, making it almost impossible to display each element dynamically. The ideal scenario would be to load a different component for each display type, but it looks like there is no easy way to achieve this.

Some options I have been thinking of were the following:

- Using `dom-if` but it would add crap to my resulting HTML.
- Is there a `dom-switch`? If it were something like that and didn't leave empty template tags (as it would do with `dom-if`) it would be nice.
- It's possible to load a component dynamically? Using something like this: `<[[item.type]] item-configuration=[[item.configuration]]></[[item.type]]>`

Any other ideas? I would really appreciate any ideas or solutions or at least a workaround for my issue.

Comment: By load you don't mean `<link rel="import" />`, right?

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR;** you can't

Polymer (and Web Components in general I guess) are best when used in a declarative way. Out-of-the-box your best solution is dynamically creating elements and adding to DOM or messy use of `dom-if`.

**(potential) OPTION 1**

I guess you could fairly easily implement a `dom-switch` element to work like

```
<template-switch switch="[[some.value]]">
  <template-case case="10">
     <element-one></element-one>
  </template-case>

  <template-case case="20">
     <element-two></element-two>
  </template>

  <template-default>
     <element-one></element-one>
  </template-default>
</dom-switch>
```

I wrote this off the top of my head. There are multiple ways to implement such an element. A crucial decision is whether to use `<template>` internally or not. In [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/WERpEP) I've implemented such element without templates but simply using content distribution.

**OPTION 2**

There is also [`Polymer.Templatizer`](http://t-code.pl/blog/2015/08/polymer-templatizer/).

Faced with a similar issue of choosing element to render dynamically I created [this Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/pQ6NOd?p=info) as a proof of concept.

As you see, you extend the `<template>` element with custom rules, which match against a model. You then bind the matched template's nodes with the model using `Polymer.Templatizer`.

Thanks to Templatizer, you don't have to pollute your actual element with conditionals and still get full binding functionality.

I'm working on a more feature-complete solution. If you're interested I could move it to a separate repository and publish.

Comment: Polymer.Templatizer seems promising for a quick (and efficient) solution. Also the first option looks cool but I guess I will try with something that actually exists. I will tell you later how things goes for me. Thanks in advance!